# Python - Assign a type to a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a `Python` application that inserts dictionary records into a `MongoDB` (via `PyMongo`).

The dictionary records are read from lines of a `CSV` file (its actually a tab-separated, but same difference).

To read the `CSV` file and insert each line into `MongoDB`, I am using the code:

```
with open(input_file, 'r') as f_h:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f_h, delimiter='\t')
    records = []
    for record in reader:
        records.append(record)
        if len(records) % 100 == 0:
            db.add_record(table_name, records) #MongoDB helper method
            records = []
```

This works quite well, except that **ALL** my values are of type `string`, when in fact, I have `int` and `float` values in the records as well. I *think* Python has the ability to determine a type, but I'm unsure how to implement this in the above code. Does anyone have any idea about this?

**UPDATE:**

Both `sihrc` and `Joran`'s answers pointed me the correct direction. However, I wanted to update with the full working implementation. My question included how would I change the cast of each element of the dictionary before I send it to MongoDB. To do this, I had to put their code in a loop over each `key/value` pair in the dictionary.

```
for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
        try:
            dictionary[key] = int(value)
        except: pass
        try:
            dictionary[key] = float(value)
        except: pass

    return dictionary
```

Works like a charm now. Wish I could accept two answers!

Comment: are you trying to read the type out of your input_file? You can try casting within try catches..

Comment: I suppose I may need to, but that's what I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sihrc almost has the solution

```
def convertType(value):
   if value.strip().isdigit():
       return int(value)
   try:
       return float(value)
   except: 
       pass    
   return value
```

you need to do it in this order

since `float("1")` will cast fine and return a float(in the other solution) even though its actually an int

you can make it even shorter (maybe more readable)

```
def convertType(value):
   try:
       return int(value) if value.strip().isdigit() else float(value)
   except: 
       return value # or None or float("-inf") or something depending on desired behavior
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(input_file, 'r') as f_h:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f_h, delimiter='\t')
    records = []
    for record in reader:
        records.append(convertType(record))
        if len(records) % 100 == 0:
            db.add_record(table_name, records) #MongoDB helper method
            records = []

def convertType(value):
   try:
       return float(value)
   except: pass
   try:
       return int(value)
   except:
       return value
```

Comment: +1 ... although you can just `try: return cast(value)` instead of assigning to a variable just to return it.. also your logic is slightly off